# If outer class(enclosing class) and inner class have data member with same names then how can we differentiate them

Tags: java, oop

If we have a class like the following which have data members with same names in *inner* and *outer* **class**, how can we **differentiate** them? like if I want to calculate the **sum** of *inner* two int it will be simply a+b, but what about **outerSum**?

```
public class OuterClass {
    int a;
    int b;
    class innerClass{
        int a;
        int b;
        int innerSum = a+b;
        int outerSum = ?;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:c++]?

Comment: See @Smurf's answer as to how to resolve this, but you're probably better off with better variable naming.

Comment: o common @Yakk ......can't we use nested classes in c++????

Comment: @AwaisMajeed Yes, but they are almost completely unrelated to how nested classes work in Java.  They are nested, they use the class keyword, but almost every other detail is different.

Comment: can you elaborate this a little bit please...... any reference I can study???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int outerSum = OuterClass.this.a + OuterClass.this.b;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code snippet

```
int outerSum = OuterClass.this.a + OuterClass.this.b;
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.